# Zebra Printer-Barcode printing format

Tags: printing, barcode, zebra-printers

I want to print a Code 128 barcode through print to file.What text format I have to send.
Content-01 Numeric data 17 Numeric data 10 Variable data.

Please give me the formula.

With Regards
DS

Answer (score 0):

you use ZPL to communicate with the printer.  The ZPL syntax for printing Code 128 barcodes is here: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/code_128.htm

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Can we use direct printing for label printer (Zebra zp450). I'm able to print single barcode with below logic.Also it's printing correctly in a4 papers.

```
float x = leftMargin;
            float y = topMargin;
            for (; _iCount <= barcodeRows; _iCount++)
            {
                float lineTop = y;
                for (int j = 1; j <= perLine; j++)
                {
                    BarcodeDraw bdraw = BarcodeDrawFactory.GetSymbology(BarcodeSymbology.Code128);
                    Image barcodeImage = bdraw.Draw(txtBarcode.Text, barcodeHeight);
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(barcodeImage, new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt16(x), Convert.ToInt16(y), barcodeWidth, barcodeHeight));
                    y = lineTop;
                    printCount++;
                }
                x = leftMargin;
                y = y + (80+ 20);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get the ZPL code (the Zebra printers native code) is to generate a label with the desired barcode with Zebradesigner software (free of charge on the zebra website), then use the "print to file" option you can find in the print menu.
This will save a text file which includes all the required commands to print the label.